# WebClient returning null after making a request to the reddit api

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, webclient

I am trying to write a backend to integrate with reddits API, I created a web client with my app clientId and secret which works fine for this request

```
webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/v1/me")
            .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("reddit"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() { })
            .block();
```

this returns a valid response as a String, since I have been testing my implementation I haven't introduced any models yet; on the other side the request that I make to retrieve a random post from /r/theonion subreddit returns null without any exceptions.

```
webClient.get()
            .uri("/r/theonion/random")
            .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("reddit"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() { })
            .block();
```

This request just returns null and I have no idea what is wrong with it since I am not getting any exceptions and the similar request(the one above) is working fine. Also after authenticating myself with postman using the app clientId and secret, I can execute this call and get a response.
[image] Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you do `bodyToMono(String.class)`?

Comment: Same result the response returns null

Comment: Are you using Netty as backend for WebClient? If so, maybe you try to enable debug (or even trace) to investigate the request/response ? logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient: DEBUG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason, it turns out the random endpoint for Reddit returns a 302 redirect which redirects to a real request to retrieve a random post so enabling the redirect for WebClient solved the issue for me. I used netty HttpClient to enable the redirects so adding this solved the issue for me:

.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector( HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)))